# File upload form with Vue JS & Laravel - trying to show list of uploaded files?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have built a file upload form with VueJS inside a component, and I am submitting the data with axios and via a post request to the back end (Laravel) where I am saving the name of the file in a database.

I am looking fror a way to loop through all the files uploaded already and display them one at a time in the view. I expect this would be done inside the Vue component, but I don't know if I need to redirect back to this component after the file saving in the laravel controller, or use a 'v-for' loop in the vue code. Either way, I cannot get a list to appear at the moment.

It would also be nice to see a small image (logo) of the file next to each upload.

Vue code:

```html
<template>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="upload">
         <label>File
         <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
         </label>
         <button v-on:click="submitFile()">Submit</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
   import axios from 'axios';
   
   export default {
    /* Defines the data used by the component */
    data(){
      return {
        file: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
        /* Submits the file to the server */
        submitFile(){
            /* Initialize the form data */
            let formData = new FormData();
            
            formData.append('file', this.file); /* possibly add a validation here to make sure the file variable contains an actual file. */
   
            axios.post('/single-file',
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
            ).then(function(){
                console.log('SUCCESS!!');
            }).catch(function(){
                console.log('FAILURE!!');
            });
        },
        handleFileUpload(){
            this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
            /* we set the local file variable to the first File object in the FileList
            on the input[type="file"].  The this.$refs.file refers to the ref
            attribute on the input[type="file"]. This makes it easily accesible within our component */
        }
    }
   }
</script>
```

PHP Code (backend controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SpaController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('spa');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $file = new File();

        // read file contents.
        $file->name = $request
            ->files
            ->get('file')
            ->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->save();

        return response()
            ->json(['success' => 'You have successfully upload a file.']);
    }
}
```

App.js (showing the vue router):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

window.Vue = require('vue')

Vue.use(VueRouter) // imports and installs the VueRouter plugin

import App from '../views/App' // imports three Vue components
import Hello from '../views/Hello'
import Home from '../views/Home'

const router = new VueRouter({ // constructs a new VueRouter instance that takes a config object
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/hello',
            name: 'hello',
            component: Hello,
        }
    ],
});

const app = new Vue({ // Make Vue aware of the App component by passing it to the components property in the Vue constructor.
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        App
    },
    router, // We inject the router constant into the new Vue application to get access to this.$router and this.$route.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean to display the image to be uploaded? You can use the FileReader API for this problem. But on the other hand, if you want to display the results of the uploaded image you can provide a response from your API Laravel in the form of an image link to front-end and display it on the Vue component via a callback.

API FileReader: https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader